# % java Classname arg < filname

Tags: java, eclipse, file, input, args

I'm trying to test some code (from this [link](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/22library/IFS.java.html)).

When I copy this code in Eclipse like the following : (Std,StDraw and StdArrayIO are libraries I have imported,built path in my Eclipse project)

```
    public class IFS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // number of iterations
        int T = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        // probability distribution for choosing each rule
        double[] dist = StdArrayIO.readDouble1D();

        // update matrices
        double[][] cx = StdArrayIO.readDouble2D();
        double[][] cy = StdArrayIO.readDouble2D();

        // current value of (x, y)
        double x = 0.0, y = 0.0;

        // do T iterations of the chaos game
        for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) { 

            // pick a random rule according to the probability distribution
            int r = StdRandom.discrete(dist); 

            // do the update
            double x0 = cx[r][0]*x + cx[r][1]*y + cx[r][2]; 
            double y0 = cy[r][0]*x + cy[r][1]*y + cy[r][2]; 
            x = x0; 
            y = y0; 

            // draw the resulting point
            StdDraw.point(x, y); 

            // for efficiency, display only every 100 iterations
            if (t % 100 == 0) StdDraw.show(10);
        } 

        // ensure everything gets drawn
        StdDraw.show(0);
    } 
} 

% java IFS 2000 < tree.txt
```

I get the following error message :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
>
> at IFS.main(IFS.java:2)

My file tree is in the same folder of my IFS.java

Answer (score 0):

StdArrayIO, StdDraw, etc. are probably not in your class path. You need to add the jar or the java files to your project.  You should be able to see the compilation errors in the problems view of eclipse.  I get the following:

[image]

To add the jar file to the class path: right click on the project, select properties and select Java Build path and then Add Jars.. then select the jar that contains these classes:

[image]

Comment: Actually I built the path for jar files too. I didn't have the errors you mentionned :/. I used other programs using the same libraries, and not using the command " % java program arg" 

I just changed i.e , // number of iterations
        int T = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);    , args[0] into some arbitrary N, to run my program.

Comment: when you run the application from the cmd line include a class path specification.  Something like: "% java -classpath ./path/to/myjarfile.jar program arg"

Comment: Thanks John, I figured out I didn't know how to use a console...

I used to put "% java program args" in my code under Public class closing "}"...

ok I learned something !

But now I tried doing the right way. 
  1. compiling my code
  2. try to write in my console my call like "% java IFS arg < fileinput"

But at compiling time, i get the following error

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at IFS.main(IFS.java:29) "